# Powershell long string with "`n" appears fine in console but get .count = 1

Tags: powershell

I'm manipulating a test where I use multiple `.replace` commands to format the text.

For example

```
$str="hello%worldZZZniceZZZtoZZZmeet"
$str.Replace("%","`n").replace("ZZZ","`n")
```

Output in the console is good but I need to iterate each line.
problem is `$str.count = 1` meaning powershell looks at this string still as one line even when it shows up good in the console.
any idea?

## Edit:

If I output the string to file and then read the file it does read with new lines but there's a better way I'm sure instead of outputting to file and then reading it back again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to [*split*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.2) the *string* and get an *array* as result:

```
$str = "hello%worldZZZniceZZZtoZZZmeet"
$str -split "%|ZZZ"
($str -split "%|ZZZ").count # => 5
```

Since the operator is *regex* compatible you can use `"%|ZZZ"` (split on `%` or `ZZZ`).

Answer (score 4):

Strings in .NET are immutable, meaning they always return a new string instead of modifying the current string, therefore after you run `` $str.Replace("%","`n").replace("ZZZ","`n") `` the original string is still unchanged. You need to store the result to a new variable if you want to deal with it

```
PS C:\Users> $newstr = $str.Replace("%","`n").replace("ZZZ","`n")
PS C:\Users> $newstr
hello
world
nice
to
meet
PS C:\Users> $str
hello%worldZZZniceZZZtoZZZmeet
```

But even then `$newstr` is still a string which [doesn't have any `count` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0). I don't know what you want to do with `count`. If you want to get the number of lines in the variable then just use `Measure-Object`

```
PS C:\Users> $newstr | Measure-Object -Line

Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
    5


PS C:\User> ($newstr | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
5
```

Comment: FYI: almost all objects in Powershell have a "count" property, even if the original type doesn't has that property within .NET.

Comment: @bluuf it's the [Count method of LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0) and isn't a property, and obviously since the object is a single string it'll always be 1 anyway